# How to set individual capabilities on a taxonomy? Or how to re-register an existing taxonomy?

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy, user-roles, capabilities

The default taxonomy, category. By default, only those with the `edit_posts` capability can assign categories during post creation/editing.

I have a role with very limited capabilities. I want to let users in this role be able to assign categories during custom-post-type creation/editing, but I cannot give them the `edit_posts` capability and they should not be able to edit the taxonomy, only assign it.

How can I do this? Setting `'assign_terms' => 'read'` is one option, but how can I set that value without having to re-register the taxonomy?

Or alternatively, how can I give my low-level role permission to assign the taxonomy?

Comment: The user have to can assign terms only to post published by himself/herself or even published by others?

Comment: Sorry, the previous is a stupid question. You don't want they can edit nothing, just create, I'm wrong?

Comment: That's right, the user should only be able o assign categories to the custom posts he has created. I'm going to try your code, one second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should works

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_category_again', 1 );

function register_category_again() {
  $user = wp_get_current_user();
  if ( $user->roles[0] != 'your_custom_role' ) return;
  global $wp_taxonomies;
  unset( $wp_taxonomies['category'] );
  global $wp_rewrite;
  $rewrite = array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'slug' => get_option('category_base') ? get_option('category_base') : 'category',
    'with_front' => ! get_option('category_base') || $wp_rewrite->using_index_permalinks(),
    'ep_mask' => EP_CATEGORIES,
  );
  register_taxonomy( 'category', 'post', array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'query_var' => 'category_name',
    'rewrite' => $rewrite,
    'public' => true,
    'capabilities' => array(
      'manage_terms'=> 'manage_categories',
      'edit_terms'=> 'manage_categories',
      'delete_terms'=> 'manage_categories',
      'assign_terms' => 'read'
    ),
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    '_builtin' => true,
  ) );
}
```

Comment: Incredible, works like a charm. I would have never been able to do it without your help. I thought the answer was going to be a one-liner, but it turned out to be more complex than I expected. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome. Unset standard category is one line (maybe two) _problem_ is register it again _exactly_ how WP do, to avoid bugs. However, for the scope I just copied out the WP code. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I just found this question and although it might work, I was not satisfied with the solution. There had to be a better way to do this, without registering the taxonomy again. And there is a better solution, I am now using in my CPT plugin.

```
public function wpse_108219_set_taxonomy_caps( $taxonomy, $object_type, $args ) {
    global $wp_taxonomies;

    if ( 'category' == $taxonomy && 'cpt_item' == $object_type ) {
        $wp_taxonomies[ $taxonomy ]->cap->assign_terms = 'edit_cpt_items';
    }

}

add_filter( 'registered_taxonomy', 'wpse_108219_set_taxonomy_caps' ), 10, 3 );
```

In this example, I set the `assign_terms` capability for the custom post type `cpt_item` to the custom capability `edit_cpt_items` which enables any user with this capability to assign categories to the CPT.

I hope this cleaner solution also works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could also filter core's category args before the taxonomy is registered:

```
<?php
/*
 * Set the capabilities for the category taxonomy before it's registered.
 *
 * @param array  $args        Array of arguments for registering a taxonomy.
 * @param array  $object_type Array of names of object types for the taxonomy.
 * @param string $taxonomy    Taxonomy key.
 */
function wpse_108219_register_taxonomy_args( $args, $taxonomy, $object_type ) {

    if ( 'category' === $taxonomy ) {

        $args['capabilities'] = array(
            'manage_terms' => 'manage_categories',
            'edit_terms'   => 'manage_categories',
            'delete_terms' => 'manage_categories',
            'assign_terms' => 'read',
        );

    }

    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'register_taxonomy_args', 'wpse_108219_register_taxonomy_args', 10, 3 );
```